# Ensure my SQL is not injected receiving array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-injection

I need to receive an array of values of like:

```
['restaurant']
['restaurant', 'pharmacy']
```

I would like which approach to take to ensure that when I use this:

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE type IN (array_joined_with_commas_and_quotes)
```

I don't get injection attacks.

I am writing the sentence without any library and I am working in Rails.

I don't have Active Record, I am doing a postgis query to an external server.

Comment: `array_joined_with_commas_and_quotes` should be parameterized, like any other query parameter.

Comment: how does this can be done? can you provide a link where I can read about it

Comment: The way Chris Travers describes.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the ActiveRecord functions for query building?
If you use rails, the gem should still be there.

```
Place.where(:type => ['foo', 'bar']).to_sql
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I am going to test, although I don't have any local database. FYI, I use another gem to make a POST request to the external server that returns JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You have two basic approaches (using ? for parameterization in these examples).

If this is an array, then your `['restaurant', 'pharmacy']` becomes `'{"restaurant","pharmacy"}'` and then you can:

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE type = ANY (?);
```

You could also

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE type IN (? ....);
```

Dynamically generating the number of parameters as you go.  As scones mentioned ActiveRecord may be able to automate this for you.  The point though is that these methods send data separately from the query, which means that the SQL cannot be injected into the query.

Comment: In Active Record I think I would use to do something like this: `Place.where('type IN (?)', array)`, but I actually don't understand how to apply your solution. Do you mean that the method that makes the query (I am using https://github.com/Vizzuality/cartodb-rb-client) should me allow to write prepared statements? is that the right  name: prepared statement?

Comment: There are actually a couple options.  If you have good Pg array support `= any(?)` is the cleanest.  If not you can implement array support easily if you have csv support.  It's basically a csv surrounded by `{}` and then you can use `= ANY`